# p11tool doesn't list my smart card on Ubuntu 17

Tags: certificates, openconnect, smartcard

When I run `p11tool --list-tokens` on Ubuntu 17 the certificates from my USB connected Sitecom smart card reader don't show up in the results. I was hoping to use p11tool to get the URL of the certificate I need to use to connect to my company's VPN using OpenConnect.

- I am confident the card reader is detected and works. I used the PCSC-lite and CCID open source drivers from https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/. When I use their verification tool ([PCSC-perl](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-perl/)) it shows me

`Card state: Card inserted, Shared Mode`

.. and it responds immediately when I take the card out by telling me:

`Card state: Card removed`

- I installed opensc and opensc-pkcs11 (https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki). I have two opensc.module files on my system, because I wasn't sure where to put them:

  /etc/pkcs11/modules/opensc.module

  /usr/share/p11-kit/modules/opensc.module

Both files' contents are the same:

`module:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so`

I verified that opensc-pksc11.so exists.

Any idea where to go from here? My smart card isn't listed in the output from `p11tool --list-tokens`, so I can't get the certificate URL that I need to connect to the VPN using OpenConnect. Output from p11tool:

```
Token 0:
    URL: pkcs11:model=p11-kit-trust;manufacturer=PKCS%2311%20Kit;serial=1;token=System%20Trust
    Label: System Trust
    Type: Trust module
    Manufacturer: PKCS#11 Kit
    Model: p11-kit-trust
    Serial: 1
    Module: p11-kit-trust.so


Token 1:
    URL: pkcs11:model=1.0;manufacturer=Gnome%20Keyring;serial=1%3aSSH%3aHOME;token=SSH%20Keys
    Label: SSH Keys
    Type: Generic token
    Manufacturer: Gnome Keyring
    Model: 1.0
    Serial: 1:SSH:HOME
    Module: gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so


Token 2:
    URL: pkcs11:model=1.0;manufacturer=Gnome%20Keyring;serial=1%3aSECRET%3aMAIN;token=Secret%20Store
    Label: Secret Store
    Type: Generic token
    Manufacturer: Gnome Keyring
    Model: 1.0
    Serial: 1:SECRET:MAIN
    Module: gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so


Token 3:
    URL: pkcs11:model=1.0;manufacturer=Gnome%20Keyring;serial=1%3aUSER%3aDEFAULT;token=Gnome2%20Key%20Storage
    Label: Gnome2 Key Storage
    Type: Generic token
    Manufacturer: Gnome Keyring
    Model: 1.0
    Serial: 1:USER:DEFAULT
    Module: gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so


Token 4:
    URL: pkcs11:model=1.0;manufacturer=Gnome%20Keyring;serial=1%3aXDG%3aDEFAULT;token=User%20Key%20Storage
    Label: User Key Storage
    Type: Generic token
    Manufacturer: Gnome Keyring
    Model: 1.0
    Serial: 1:XDG:DEFAULT
    Module: gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
```

Below is th output of `lsusb`. When I remove the card reader from the USB port the Realtek Semiconductor entry disappears, so I assume the card reader is recognized by the OS. However, I am not sure why it is called "Realtek" since it is a Sitecom reader, but I assume Realtek is just the chip manufacturer. Also, it is not a Storage Device. When I use the card on Windows it will sometimes try to assign a drive letter to the card and access it, which fails. Maybe the card reader inaccurately reports it is a storage device?

```
me@me:/etc/pkcs11/modules$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0169 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```